# Angular router url without param

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

I want to use id when requesting data but not show it id url.

```
[routerLink]="['/', category.slug, {id: category.categoryId}]"
```

This results in url '/cameras;id=3' where id 3 is the cameras category.
It works but I would like to have a clean url like '/cameras' only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are encoded in url (you can even customize this encoding), but it is not possible to hide them, hiding in this case === completely removing.

You may use workaround using shared service and pass parameters using this service when navigating within application, but in this case you will not be able to share links, because it will not contain parameter value.

Comment: Ah ok.. then how can I pass the id.. is there another way than a router param?

Comment: @Mackelito, butting in here, but as to your question, do it like kemsky said in answer, store the id in your service, fetch it in the component you are navigating to :)